# Trying to delete crypto partitions from debian graphical installer

Tags: system-installation, debian

I'm setting up manual partitions (I made 2 crypto ones) on debian wheezy using the graphical installer, but I didn't leave enought space for the boot one. So I am trying to delete them but am not able to.

How can I do this?

I'm doing it manually cause I have a windows boot partition on the same drive.

Comment: "I am trying to delete them but am not able to." Please give details of what commands you are using. Why don't use the installer to delete the partitions?

Comment: graphical installer doesn't allow to delete them

Comment: I see. That is rather surprising.